# pyspark - how can I remove all duplicate rows (ignoring certain columns) and not leaving any dupe pairs behind?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following table:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2,'john',1),
                            (2,'john',1),
                            (3,'pete',8),
                            (3,'pete',8),
                            (5,'steve',9)],
                           ['id','name','value'])

df.show()

+----+-------+-------+--------------+
| id | name  | value |     date     |
+----+-------+-------+--------------+
|  2 | john  |     1 | 131434234342 |
|  2 | john  |     1 | 10-22-2018   |
|  3 | pete  |     8 | 10-22-2018   |
|  3 | pete  |     8 | 3258958304   |
|  5 | steve |     9 | 124324234    |
+----+-------+-------+--------------+
```

I want to remove all duplicate pairs (When the duplicates occur in id, name, or value but NOT date) so that I end up with:

```
+----+-------+-------+-----------+
| id | name  | value |   date    |
+----+-------+-------+-----------+
|  5 | steve |     9 | 124324234 |
+----+-------+-------+-----------+
```

How can I do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could groupBy `id`, `name` and `value` and filter on the `count` column : :

```
df = df.groupBy('id','name','value').count().where('count = 1')

df.show()

+---+-----+-----+-----+
| id| name|value|count|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  5|steve|    9|    1|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

You could eventually drop the `count` column if needed

Answer (score 1):

Do `groupBy` for the columns you want and `count` and do a filter where `count` is equal to `1` and then you can drop the `count` column like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.groupBy("id", "name", "value").agg(f.count("*").alias('cnt')).where('cnt = 1').drop('cnt')
```

You can add the `date` column in the `GroupBy` condition if you want

Hope this helps you

Comment: it might be easier to use `Window` function so all columns will be kept.